# Питон не видит библиотеку vk_api. Что делать?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Устанавливал через pip3 install vk_api. Не помогло

Comment: с чего ты взял, что не видит?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\другое\vkbot\avtootvetchik.py", line 2, in <module>
    import vk_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vk_api'`

Comment: Ну так она вообще установилась? Какой вывод был после ``pip3 install vk_api``?

Comment: Значит, у вас не установился он

Comment: Или просто неправильно импортируешь, так бывает.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать это:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'vk_api'])
import vk_api

#Ваш код
```

Comment: `pip.main(['install', 'vk_api'])` - это дичь, не нужно так делать. Вместо этого нужно разобраться, куда установился модуль. Скорее всего обычная проблема: установил глобально, а запускает из виртуального окружения, или наоборот.

Comment: Да, по сути вы правы. Это решение по большей части для тех случаев, когда нет доступа к терминалу (сам с таким сталкивался)